# Fetch domain name from anchor tag value using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I have below mix content in a php string.

```
<div class="biz-website">
    <span class="offscreen">Business website</span>
    <a target="_blank" href="/biz_redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&amp;src_bizid=LihgJyPNjlUB3euiFvfEgw&amp;cachebuster=1419609400&amp;s=112daf4cc534d37cbf02a548cb8cb1d15bbeba6fab83b74b1195640dc44c040e">example.com</a>
</div>
```

I need to fetch **example.com** from above php string. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No I have not try but I know we can do this by using preg_match function

Comment: @LalitSharma: Actually, you can't do this with `preg_match` (well, you *can*, but you ***shouldn't***).

Comment: P.S. What do you mean by "what I am doing wrong"?  We can't answer that question.  You didn't show us what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex is not the right tool here.  The *correct* tool is a DOM parser.  I like PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/domdocument).

```
$html = <<<END
<div class="biz-website">
    <span class="offscreen">Business website</span>
    <a target="_blank" href="/biz_redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&amp;src_bizid=LihgJyPNjlUB3euiFvfEgw&amp;cachebuster=1419609400&amp;s=112daf4cc534d37cbf02a548cb8cb1d15bbeba6fab83b74b1195640dc44c040e">example.com</a>
</div>
END;

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$aTags = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');

$value = $aTags->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $value;
```

UPDATE: If you want to see if the `href` contains `"biz_redir"`, then you can just simply check that:

```
$html = <<<END
<div class="biz-website">
    <span class="offscreen">Business website</span>
    <a target="_blank" href="/biz_redir?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&amp;src_bizid=LihgJyPNjlUB3euiFvfEgw&amp;cachebuster=1419609400&amp;s=112daf4cc534d37cbf02a548cb8cb1d15bbeba6fab83b74b1195640dc44c040e">example.com</a>
</div>
END;

$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);

$aTags = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('a');
$aTag = $aTags->item(0);

if(strpos($aTag->getAttribute('href'), 'biz_redir') !== FALSE){
    $value = $aTag->nodeValue;
    echo $value;
}
```

UPDATE 2: If you don't just have that clip, but the *entire* webpage, then you can find the `<div>` you want like this:

```
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($DOM);

$biz = $xPath->query('//div[@class="biz-website"]/a[contains(@href, "biz_redir")]');

$value = $biz->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $value;
```

Comment: I want to check also if anchor tag's href contains biz_redir then only we have to fetch its value which is between <a href="biz_redir" >example.com</a>

Comment: @LalitSharma: You can check the `href` attribute, too.  I'll add that in the answer.  (P.S. Try to say what you want upfront)

Comment: I want to fetch address from http://www.yelp.com/biz/h-und-m-wien-4 you can find that website written under the contact number which is "hm.com" using php

Comment: @LalitSharma: OH!  Well, then you might need to loop over all the `<a>` tags to find the one with `"biz_redir"`.  Or, actually, there's a `<div class="biz-website">`.  If you search for that, then you can easily get the `<a>`.

Comment: @LalitSharma: Do you have just the string you show in the question, or do you have the *entire* page that you want to search in?

Comment: I am going to use file_get_contents php function to get whole page's html and then will fetch values i required

Comment: @LalitSharma: You can actually have DOMDocument get the page for you, instead of using `file_get_contents`.  Replace `$DOM->loadHTML($html);` with `$DOM->load('http://www.yelp.com/biz/h-und-m-wien-4');` :-)

Comment: I have try but its giving me null

Comment: Thanks buddy working greate :)